# how can I use Split Method to parse this set of numbers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, split

[image]

How can I implement a Split Method to parse just the highlighted object/numbers?

Comment: Do you have just the value of `1.0.89`? Or are you trying to parse it out of the value `.../gateway:1.0.89`? Please remove the image and provide the value you are trying to parse/split as text with expected results. Also adding a coding attempt of your own would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   string version;
 string asp = "3ac2b3920ebe  myplantcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/gateway:1.0.89 dotnet AspWebAppT...  2 days ago    Exited (0) About an hour ago  0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp  asptest9";
  string pattern = "(:)";
  string[] split = Regex.Split(asp, pattern);
       
    if (split.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(version = split[2]);
            
        }
```

**with the code the output is: 1.0.89 dotnet AspWebAppT...  2 days ago    Exited (0) About an hour ago  0.0.0.0**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative would be using regular expressions, but since you are asking about split:

Not a single split, but a series of splits.

First split using `:` character, would give you an array 2 strings:

- First would contain `...azurecr.io/getaway`
- Second would contain `0.14.0-dev-...`

Now the second split would be using the `-` character and would give you an array of 1 or more items (depending on what line would you parse).

- First would contain what you need `0.14.0`
- The rest would have the other trash you do not want (`dev`, `159`, `g9dd28953`)

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you so much. I'll give this one a shot and see what happens.

Comment: So, I did use Regex.Split and came up with a solution and managed to have an output of "1.0.89" but it still displays the residual string "dotnet AspWebAppT... 2 days ago Exited (0) About an hour ago 0.0.0.0" I added it on the solution.